# Fortran Type Definition with a parameter list

Tags: types, fortran

Please take a look at this code, why there are problems, how could I do this instead?

```
program main
type matrix(m,n)
    integer::m,n
    double precision,dimension(1:m,1:n)::value
end type matrix

type(matrix(2,3))::B
print*,"OK"
end program
```

Another question about this is: Can I have a type definition or module definition followed by a parameter list? Cause I saw this code from book , don't know why I cannot compile it.

Answer (score 4):

Leaving aside MSB's observation about the point of defining `matrix`, and if you have a bang up-to-date compiler you could define and declare a *parameterized defined-type* rather like this:

```
type matrix(m,n,k)
    integer, len :: m,n
    integer, kind :: k
    real(kind=k), dimension(m,n) :: elements
end type matrix

...

type(matrix(4,3,selected_real_kind(0.0)) :: the_matrix
```

Note:

- not all the widely-used Fortran compilers yet implement this feature of the 2008 standard;
- the parameters `m,n,k` have a special attribute on their declaration, either `len` or `kind`;
- I've included the kind-type parameter just to show that it exists, it's not necessary to include it when you define a parameterised derived type.

Comment: Thanks,Looks like GNU and Intel only fully support fortran95, even 2003 is partly supported, so I think that's the reason.

Comment: Almost nobody fully supports, f2003. PGI sometimes claim they do, but in reallity they it's still not complete. Also they support less features of f2008.

Comment: But how do you use `matrix` as a dummy argument but the parameters `m` and `n` not specified. For example if you were to make a function `mysum(A)` which sums up all the elements of `A = matrix(m,n)`

Answer (score 2):

```
program main

type matrix
    integer:: m, n
    double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: value
end type matrix

type (matrix) :: mat1, mat2


mat1 % m = 2
mat1 % n = 3
allocate ( mat1 % value ( mat1 % m, mat1 % n ) )
mat1 % value = 5.0

mat2 % m = 4
mat2 % n = 5
allocate ( mat2 % value ( mat2 % m, mat2 % n ) )
mat2 % value = 6.0

print*,"OK"
end program
```

A good example but there is no reason to create this particular user-defined type in real code because you can obtained the bounds of a matrix with `lbound` and `ubound` -- you don't have to store them in a type.

Comment: Thanks!I got another question!