# How to use an inherited component's integer value as array length in an extension

Tags: oop, fortran, type-extension

That's what I want to do:

```
  type dataframe
     integer::a,d
     integer,dimension(:),allocatable::n
  end type dataframe

  type,extends(dataframe):: datafilled
     double precision,dimension(sum(n),d)::x
  end type datafilled
```

So the `dataframe` should be able to store the size information for its child `datafilled`. gfortran wants to know the type of `n` for compilation, but in my opinion it's already inherited. (Proof: If I define `n` in `datafilled` again, gfortran complains about the duplication.) How can I get it working?

Note: I declare `n` to be allocatable according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889326/fortran-type-definition-with-a-parameter-list/13890893#13890893) and because gfortran obviously doesn't yet support the `len` attribute of Fortran2003.

EDIT: OK, I admit I can do it with the `allocatable` attribute and `allocate` at each initialisation step later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are constraints on what can be in a component array specification, that for non-allocatable/non-pointer components allow the specification to be evaluated at compile time (at the point that a type declaration for an object of the type being defined is encountered).  Specifically, the value of a bound in the specification must not depend on the value of a variable - see C446 in F2008 for the details.

The component `n` in some object of type dataframe is a variable; calculating `sum(n)` requires its value; you are violating the constraint.

Length type parameters, even if your compiler supported them, can only be scalar.

As you've concluded - using an allocatable component, and allocating things correctly in some sort of construction procedure is the way to go.

Comment: In the beginning, I was surprised that the declaration `double precision,dimension(sum(n),d)::x` worked inside a procedure, if `n` was a variable `intent(in)`. So I was keen that this could also work in a type declaration. Up to now.